# Apache 2.4 mod_proxy DNS failure

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy

I have very strange problems with apache 2.4.18 mod_proxy on Debian Linux Testing with kernel 4.3.0 (amd64). I am using it as a forward proxy:

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
ProxyBadHeader Ignore
AllowCONNECT 1-65535
```

Right after starting the server, everything works. But after only a few requests, it stops serving requests:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET http://www.google.de/.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: www.google.de
```

If I try to add the host (in the example: www.google.de) to the /etc/hosts file, it does not change anything. Also, name resolving works normally on the server, no other service has any problems.

LogLevel trace8 shows nothing related to name resolving. It seems to me that this has actually nothing to do with DNS.

What is this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This same thing happened to me, turned out the `ProxyPass` directive had a character deleted from the end, the ending slash on the forward address.

i.e.
`ProxyPass \ https:\\foo.com`
Should have been
`ProxyPass \ https:\\foo.com\`